# Joomla Subform output

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

OK, I have tried the info from another suggestion on stackexchange, but I seem to be missing something.

I have a subform in an admin view for a component I am working on (they were previously repeatable fields). Admin works perfect, but I am having trouble getting the json to display correctly on the frontend site view.

The fields that are being pulled into the view are in a layout, so it's a little different then in the site view ($displayData instead of $items).

In the db I have a field called appliances, and 4 items in the field are {"appliances1":{"appliance_type":"Dishwasher"},"appliances2":{"appliance_type":"Range"},"appliances3":{"appliance_type":"Microwave"},"appliances4":{"appliance_type":"Washer/Dryer"}}

OK. That looks good and properly formatted.

On the frontend, in the layout for a view, I have:

```
<?php
print_r($displayData->appliances);
foreach ($displayData->appliances as $item) : ?>
<div>
<p>
<?php echo $displayData->appliance_type; ?>
</p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the print_r shows:

Appliances
Array ( [appliances1] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Dishwasher ) [appliances2] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Range ) [appliances3] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Microwave ) [appliances4] => Array ( [appliance_type] => Washer/Dryer ) )

OK. again, that looks good. I'll remove that as soon at its working properly.

The problem is that

```
<p>
<?php echo $displayData->appliance_type; ?>
</p>
```

doesn't display anything.

I can see in the code, that it's doing the foreach correctly, but it's not grabbing anything from the array:

```
            Array
(
    [appliances1] => Array
        (
            [appliance_type] => Dishwasher
        )

    [appliances2] => Array
        (
            [appliance_type] => Range
        )

    [appliances3] => Array
        (
            [appliance_type] => Microwave
        )

    [appliances4] => Array
        (
            [appliance_type] => Washer/Dryer
        )

)
<div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>
</p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

Comment: Please could you format the code in your question so it's a little easier to read?

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic errors.  1. You assign each item in the array to the variable $item and then you don't use it. 2. You use arrow syntax to refer to an array. Having errors displaying would have helped you work through this.

```
foreach ($displayData->appliances as $item) : ?>
<div>
<p>
<?php echo $item['appliance_type']; ?>
</p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```